# How to get all days, months, and years in a drop down?

Tags: php, calendar

Is there a class or a php script that will echo in drop down fields all the days, months, and years.  I need to use them for date of birth fields.  I googled but nothing came up that i can implement or learn from.  ANy ideas? thanks

Comment: still not sure what u need to do? is this on client or server side?

Comment: i am using this for a registration form.  you know you have your date of birth fields.  so i want to be able to show all the days, months, years up to current date in the field.

Comment: PHP is not your best option for this, due to the varying number of days per month. You would have to submit the form when `Month` is selected in order to get the correct `Day` count.

Comment: Ok, assuming you're allowing for 120yo people to register, that's 365*120 = 43,800 rows in your dropdown box. Utterly insane. Best to split it into seperate day/month/year fields, or you'll break the internet sending that many `<option>` sets. And then don't forget leapyears, which is about 30 more option fields, so 44,100 in total.

Comment: @Marc B: I think you're multiplying when you should be adding. ;)  `120 + 12 + 31` .. I doubt he's going to make a single `<select>` with: `2011-03-28`, `2011-03-27`, `2011-03-26` etc. etc.

Comment: True enough.. but imagine the horror...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**If you REALLY just want it done in PHP, here's a simple start:**

```
<?php
    // lowest year wanted
    $cutoff = 1910;

    // current year
    $now = date('Y');

    // build years menu
    echo '<select name="year">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($y=$now; $y>=$cutoff; $y--) {
        echo '  <option value="' . $y . '">' . $y . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;

    // build months menu
    echo '<select name="month">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
        echo '  <option value="' . $m . '">' . date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m)) . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;

    // build days menu
    echo '<select name="day">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($d=1; $d<=31; $d++) {
        echo '  <option value="' . $d . '">' . $d . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

---

**Another method, similar output:**
*(Years will be in Ascending order, rather than Descending)*

```
<?php
    $build = array(
        array('year', '1910', date('Y'), 'Y'),
        array('month', '1', '12', 'M'),
        array('day', '1', '31', 'j')
    );
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    foreach ($build as $item) {
        $menu = $doc->createElement('select');
        $menu->setAttribute('name', $item[0]);
        for ($x=$item[1]; $x<=$item[2]; $x++) {
            $b = $item[3];
            $opt = $doc->createElement('option');
            $opt->setAttribute('value', $x);
            $opt->nodeValue = date($item[3], mktime(0,0,0,($b=='M'?$x:1),($b=='j'?$x:1),($b=='Y'?$x:1)));
            $menu->appendChild($opt);
        }
        $doc->appendChild($menu);
    }
    echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

Comment: This one still works, but for insert into mysql DATE field you need the leading zeros. With: sprintf("%02d", $num); inside the FOR loops before echoing the $m and $d.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of going with three distinct `<select>`, which is not a very user-friendly solution, why not use some Javascript-based calendar widget ?

For example, I've heard about [**jQuery Datepicker**](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) quite a few times -- the effect is far better, don't you think :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/5463037.png))</sub>

*(And that's just a screenshot of the demo on the page I linked to ; there are several options you can tune)*

Comment: Yes, i discovered this while googling but i want something like a drop down.  And this is for date of birth, so imagine if you were born on 1943, you would have to keep scrolling back and back...

Comment: I believe you can just type `1943` into the text field and it will adjust to the appropriate year.

Comment: @AAA: I believe if you set the `altFormat` option to `YYYY-MM-DD`, then you can begin typing the year and have it auto-adjust.

Comment: it would be a better far batter option if it could work for recurring

Answer (score 2):

The topic is old, but would say in the accepted answer to be added

> date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m))

-->

> date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m,1))

because on 29th, 30th and 31st the labels would be wrong. PHP takes as default the current day and will return wrong months in which this day is missing. PHP will interprete it as the month + 1 day and will show the following month

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question but maybe this would help.

```
var_dump(cal_info(CAL_GREGORIAN )['months']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-info.php

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.calendar.php