# drop down list of Month and Day for birthday in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

What's the best way to get the Months and Days drop down list in PHP ?

I tried the following code, but `mktime` is depreciated :

```
 for ($j = 1; $j <= 12; $j++) 
 {
    $month_text = date("F", time(0, 0, 0, $j+1, 0, 0, 0));
    $month[$j] = $month_text;
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout DateTime, http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it much more complex than it needs to be. Just put the names of the months in an array and use `range()` to create the array of days.

```
$months = array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
$days = range(1, 31);
```

If you want the month number to coincide with the month name just add an empty array element to the beginning of the month array.

Comment: do I have to write down the months in an array like that?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? There is no better way.

Comment: How about months that do not have 31 days?

Comment: @RonniSkansing If they were only outputting days for only one month they would need to make the code smarter to account for the actual number of days in the month. But since their code seems to be more generic and offering options for all 12 months we need to set this to 31 days so it has all of the days for each month. If they wanted to they could add JavaScript to update that value when a month is selected. But that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I dont care about the month doesnt have 31 , its just a drop down menue selection

Comment: I also noticed something here the months[0] = Januaray ? and days[0] = 1 , i need it months[1] = January and days[1] = 1 and so on

Comment: The second part of my answer accounts for that. Just add an empty element to the beginning of the array: `$months = array("", "January",` and `range(0, 31)`

Comment: but I dont need days[0] to show in there :) because I put it in HTML select option

Comment: You can easily skip it in your loop. Start at 1.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, there is a way to directly compute the number of days in a month arithmetically. See [the Gregorian Calendar article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Description)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before here: [How to get all days, months, and years in a drop down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463037/how-to-get-all-days-months-and-years-in-a-drop-down)

This is what he did, but keep in mind that he did use mktime which as you say is deprecated. To avoid making a list for year, do this:

```
<?php

    // build months menu
    echo '<select name="month">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
        echo '  <option value="' . $m . '">' . date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m)) . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;

    // build days menu
    echo '<select name="day">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($d=1; $d<=31; $d++) {
        echo '  <option value="' . $d . '">' . $d . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: That solution wont help me because mktime is depreciated

Comment: @user3150060 According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php it is not fully depreciated.  The depreciated constructor is the one using the parameter is_dst. This was done to encourage people to use the new timezone handling features instead.

Comment: are you saying if I use this date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m)) I wont get depreciated Warning?

Comment: My computer is not configured to run php at the moment, so I cannot verify it with code.  But it seems that way, based on the documentation.